# GNUPlot Does not show anything In Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, gnuplot

I use the terminal in my MacBook. I used homebrew to install gnuplot

```
brew install gnuplot --with-x11
```

When I type

```
gnuplot> "#myfile"
```

I go to the gnuplot gui but I cannot see any of the words that I type. Does any one know what I nedd to do in order to see the text?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're redirecting all the standard input to "myfile" using the ">", so that is why you don't see on the screen. A quick fix would be using `tee`:

```
$ gnuplot | tee myfile
```

I made a test on my MacBook and it worked. However, is there a reason why you want to record what you're typing on the fly? I would suggest opening a file, type your gnuplot commands, then on your terminal:

```
$ gnuplot plot_commands.gp
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I just wanted to see what I was typing because I wasn't able to see. It does work and thanks for the tip! I appreciate it